# Is it possible to use scp to copy files from remote to local at some predefined time in the future?

Tags: shell, command-line, scp

Can I make a call to `scp` now that will execute some time in the future? For example, I want to wait for some code to finish executing on remote and to then transfer the log file to local. I don't necessarily have access to remote at all times.

EDIT: `scp` requires a passphrase.

Comment: Does your scp require typing a passphrase?

Comment: Unfortunately `scp` requires a passphrase, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run any command in the future, use the [at command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/at.1posix.html) after your scp command:

```
at [-m][-f file][-q queuename] timespec
scp [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Where [timespec](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/at.shtml) is a specified date or time.

It will not work if you need a passphrase for scp though.

Comment: Uh, the `at` is the command name and should be the first token. Also, this doesn't work if the scp needs a passphrase.

Comment: Unfortunately `scp` requires a passphrase, I've updated the question.